# How to move to next input field when enter key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard-events

what to write after console.log('successful') so that i enter into next input field using id?

```
 <script>
    function invokeFunc() {
        addEventListener('keydown', function(evt) {
        var whichKey = checkKey(evt);
        if (whichKey == 13) {                            
            console.log('successful');
        }
        });
    }
    function checkKey(evt) {
        console.log(evt.which);
        return evt.which;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

```
if (whichKey == 13) {
    console.log('successful');
    evt.preventDefault(); // if it's inside <form> tag, you don't want to submit it
    document.getElementById('nextInputID').focus();
}
```

Comment: Assumes the event listener is being added correctly...which it is not

Answer (score 0):

my method will work if the input field is next each other like this

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

you can improve this by figuring out how to get the next input field when keycode is 13
in my case i use nextelementsibling and check if its an input (*you can add or logical || nextEl.nodeName === 'SELECT')
if nextElement is form field then focus() on it if not you done

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( el => {
            console.log(el)
            el.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
                console.log(e.keyCode);
                if(e.keyCode === 13) {
                    let nextEl = el.nextElementSibling;
                    console.log(nextEl)
                    if(nextEl.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
                        nextEl.focus();
                    }else {
                        alert('done');
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```